# Question mark in top right of screen

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I think I missed an instruction. At times question marks appear in the top right, usually in groups of 2 or 3 empty boxes, where one is highlighted with a question mark. What are those, and how do they work?

UPDATE:

Picture added (sorry it's so blurry. Also, at this point it's mostly for posterity).

[image]

Comment: Can you add more detail to the question? It's very hard to understand what you are talking about here.

Comment: A screenshot would be useful, but I hear rumours that it is just a glitch/bug

Comment: Are these question marks in the same spot as where it normally lists items you pick up?

Comment: I seem to get it if I try to call assassin's during memories where it either doesn't want me to or if I have them away liberating other colonies. During the Boston Tea Party memory, I had all 3 of my assassins sent away on a mission but one of them is in the cut scenes for the memory and walking around during.  I tried to use him to assassinate some redcoats and it gave me the question mark box even though he was walking around.  Not sure if this is because he was technically away in another colony or if I just wasn't allowed to use him to assassinate.

Comment: @turbo The first time I saw them was with Haytham, when he's alone, infiltrating a British camp and sabotaging the cannons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a glitch/bug, and it's not the only bug related to the upper right corner. After you get certain Items in the game each time that you exit the loading screen the same messages will appear there.

If you are afraid that you've missed an important message, you can always go to the Animus menu (not the map) and there you can see the animus messages.

Comment: I'm not sure where the message I thought I missed was anymore. Some more searching around the web points to the same explanation. Weird bug...